# My stylesheet has converted into a single line

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have no idea what happened but basically my css stylesheet with 1000 lines has turned into a single line stylesheet.

Questions:

1) Why has it happened?

2) What can I do to revert it back as I don't have any recent backup.

Thank you

Comment: With limited information, I have no idea as well, but you can always [beautify your css](http://www.codebeautifier.com/).

Comment: I would guess it has been minified. But most preprocessors I know minify files by creating a new one with some extension in the name like `default.css` becomes `default.min.css`. In that case the original file should still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be because the program you are using ¿? has a CSS compressor somewhere...

Depending on to many things, you could get the original CSS file.

If you can't, try to beautify the compressed one.
Here you have a few online tools to do'it.

- http://cssbeautify.com/
- http://procssor.com/
- http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the answer I needed!